# Sending data between ViewControllers without segues

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to send data between ViewControllers without using segues?

Specifically I have two ViewControllers embedded in a TabBarViewController. One is called PlayingCardViewController and the other is called HighScoreViewController. I want to pass a class HighScore from PlayingCardViewController to HighScoreViewController. I want to transfer the data from PlayingCardViewController as soon as I press the redeal button in PlayingCardViewController but I don't want to transition to the HighScoreViewController as that would be jarring for the player.

I thought about using segues and holding the HighScores in an array and passing that to all the VC's that PlayingCardViewController is connected to but I realized that that seems overly complicated and there must be a simpler way to pass the data upon hitting the redeal button.

Some relevant links
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: That "relevent" Question is enough to answer everything about this.What more do you expect?

Comment: That question involves passing data using segues, whereas I don't want to pass my data through a segue

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to do this with bullet points:

- You could implement a custom tab bar controller (your own `UITabBarController` subclass), and use this instead of a basic `UITabBarController`.
- Your `PlayingCardViewController` could have its own delegate protocol/property.
- The delegate protocol could define a method like `playingCardVC:didSetHighScore:`.
- Your tab bar controller would be the `PlayingCardViewController`'s delegate.
- The tab bar controller could keep a reference to the `HighScoreViewController`.
- When your tab bar controller gets the `playingCardVC:didSetHighScore:`, it could pass whatever you want to your `HighScoreViewController`.